# How to get the pruned random forest model after pruning?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

In a random forest regressor from Scikit Learn it is possible to set a `ccp_alpha` parameter that is related to the pruning technique ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)) and I'm using it to control my overfitting.

After applying it I would like to use this pruned model to perform hyperparameter tuning with random Search and find my best model. So, I want this pruned model.

Is it possible to get this pruned model?

Comment: What do you mean "get" the model? The model returned after your `fit` (or cross-validation) *is* indeed the pruned model, if you have specify so with a non-zero `ccp_alpha`.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the `.fit(X_train, y_train)` function to an object of the `RandomForestClassifier()` or `RandomForestRegressor()` class, the returned fitted model has already been pruned.
This happens under the hood in the sklearn implementation. Theoretically speaking too, a RandomForest is not just a combination of DecisionTrees, but is the pruned, aggregated, and using default settings, bootstrapped version of multiple large decision trees.

Rest assured, the model returned here is not overfitting due to pruning. If you do notice overfitting, I'd suggest you check the o.o.b score of your model and describe your entire data pipeline for further suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this cost complexity pruning tutorial from scikit-learn:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html

It includes a detailed explanantion of implementing pruning using cost-complexity.

Comment: The URL in this response is outdated, the updated link is here: [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html)